# Sharepoint 2010 User permissions for all sites/subsite/folders

Tags: permissions, user

We have SharePoint 2010 in our environment. I need to give report of all users who have got access to SharePoint Site.

Looking for one script which will give all users permission on all sites/subsites/document Library.

If any third party tools which doesn't required to be installed on SharePoint server let me know that too.

Comment: you might find your answers here or it can get you started...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144110/powershell-get-permission-on-spsite-spweb-and-all-list

Answer (score 0):

Sharegate. It's primarily a migration tool but has a good reporting component too and will do what you require it to above. I think you can get a free trial for 15 days too. Here's the link: http://en.share-gate.com/